# Prove whether $P(r)$ is a strictly decreasing function

Tags: derivatives, summation, finance

Prove that $P(r)$ is a strictly decreasing function of $r$ when $r$ > $-1$ and that $\lim \limits_{x \to -1+}$ $P(r)=\infty$, $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}$ $P(r) = -1 < 0$.

$P(r) = -a + $$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i(1+r)^{-i}$

Is this something where I try and take the derivative of this and use monadicity theorem? Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

do you mean $\lim_{r \to 1+}$ instead of $\lim_{x \to 1+}$? you take the derivative and see it's strictly negative given $r > -1$, so you can conclude the function is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Maybe $\lim_{x\to-1^+}$?